# Does laravel/homestead box comes with default website setup?

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I am trying to figure out if there is something wrong in my homestead setup

I am following the official [direction](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead). In the very end of the direction the tutorial said that accessing `http://homestead.app` is possible. However when I run the address in my chrome I get the `No input file specified.` message

I am not sure if this is the default page, so I checked my directory using

```
homestead ssh
```

and found out that

```
- map: /Users/Projects
  to: /home/vagrant/Projects
```

both directory doesn't have any files inside, I am not sure if this is the default behavior, but according to this [tutorial](https://laracasts.com/lessons/say-hello-to-laravel-homestead-two) there should be a list of file in the folder

```
app artisan bootsrap composer.json composer.lock ....
```

Comment: I think it would be constructive to post a comment explaining the downvotes, this will help me improve both future and present questions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember if homestead comes with a default website, but your `homestead.yaml` ( you can use `homestead edit` to open it )file should look like this:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:                        //This is where vagrant will look for your projects
    - map: ~/Code               //This is your host folder
      to: /home/vagrant/Code    //This is your homestead folder

sites:                          //These are the urls that nginx will serve
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/homestead/public
    - map: site2.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/site2/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

Usually, homestead comes with a `Code` folder where you can find the laravel project (if there is one by default).

Also, remeber to add the urls to your hosts files.